# OpenSwing: Filtering ComboColum

Tags: java, swing

I use [OpenSwing Framework](http://oswing.sourceforge.net/) in NetBeans. I have a `GridControl` with a lot columns. One of these is a `org.openswing.swing.table.column.client.ComboColum`. Now, I set this colum to be filterable via NetBeans GUI, as shown below, but no filter can be applied at runtime. All the data is correctly shown.

[image: eThe configuration panel in NetBeans]

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
 /**
   * Set column filtering.
   * @param columnFilterable column filtering is enabled
   */
  public final void setColumnFilterable(boolean columnFilterable) {
    this.columnFilterable = columnFilterable;
  }
```

and in the grid, right click the column will have a filter . it normal implements with the ORM framework or sql query , and generate the sql where idAutomezzo = '%???%'

kindly find some demo in [github](https://github.com/mcarniel/oswing/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=setColumnFilterable) , and aslo the [document](http://oswing.sourceforge.net/samples.html)